# Elementary does not see Windows 10 but instead sees recovery partition as Windows 7

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot, disk-management

I'm attempting to dual boot Windows 10 and Elementary OS. I recently upgraded to Windows 10, however upon attempting to install Elementary along Windows, the only option was to install aside Windows 7. I went back to Windows 10 to create a partition for Elementary to see if that would help at all, to no avail, still saying to install aside Windows 7 (That's the recovery partition.) I'm not sure what to do because I don't want Linux to boot into the Recovery partition instead of Windows 10.

Here are pictures to help visualize the problem https://sli.mg/a/lhOQna

Comment: try install via something else option

Answer (score 1):

I just recently installed eOS Loki along side Win10. From the pictures that you posted, it looks like you originally installed Win7 and upgraded to 10. I think that might be where the name is coming from. 
On the install options page for eOS just select something else and install on the 160 gb partition.